# Default text in textbox when page load

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Generally i saw any registration form the textboxes are filled with for example Enter first name or Enter Last name here like that how can i write like that. Is it javascript?
can u tell me how can i write that like that help me thanks

Comment: need to clarify your question, and maybe refer to an example.

Comment: i need water mark effect on textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments to the post by phoenix you could try something like this:

```
    <input type="text" value="Enter your name..." onfocus="CheckText(this, 'Enter your name...');" />
    <script language="javascript">
    function CheckText(e, text){
        if(e.value == text){
            e.value = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a [TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx).  The AJAX Control Toolkit has one.

Also, here is an example of a custom [ASP.NET Textbox Watermark](http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2009/03/watermark-aspnet-textbox-using.html).

EDIT: Example below is from link referenced above

**Control Markup:**

```
<asp:textbox id="txtSimpleSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JS Functions:**

```
function WatermarkFocus(txtElem, strWatermark) {
if (txtElem.value == strWatermark) txtElem.value = '';
}
function WatermarkBlur(txtElem, strWatermark) {
if (txtElem.value == '') txtElem.value = strWatermark;
}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
string strWatermarkSearch = "Search";
txtSimpleSearch.Text = strWatermarkSearch;
txtSimpleSearch.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "WatermarkFocus(this, '" + strWatermarkSearch + "');");
txtSimpleSearch.Attributes.Add("onblur", "WatermarkBlur(this, '" + strWatermarkSearch + "');");
```

Comment: exactly mr.rick_schott that is what i want?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested yourself, you could use JavaScript called on the `onload` event, something like:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('firstName').value = 'Enter first name'" ...>
```

You could group multiple instructions in a function and just call that on `onload`.

Or you could just set the value directly in the input:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="Enter first name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value property of the textbox to the desired text like

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="Enter text here" />
```

When input receives focus and is the value is the default one then clear the value. And if the user hasn't entered anything and when focus leaves the textbox put the default values back to the textbox.

Also make sure that you don't update database with the default value.

Comment: no no u not understand me when i place the cursor on that particular textbox the text should dissapear and i can write what i want

Comment: to do that, you'll need to add onclick="this.value=''".

Comment: That will erase your text every time you click on it. You should erase the text on the onfocus event of the input, but only if it matches your initial text.